# Why i have HTTP Error 503 using urllib and BS4?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I use BS4 to get Browse Standards by Technology from website: https://standards.globalspec.com/

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://standards.globalspec.com/"
q1 = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(q1, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

But i have an error: urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable

Could anyone see what could be causing this error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use CloudScraper to access websites that use CloudFlare DDoS Protection:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import cloudscraper

url = "https://standards.globalspec.com/"


scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
q1 = scraper.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(q1.text, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Comment: No it actually doesn't work. Have you read the HTML?  `DDoS protection by <a href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing/" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a>`

Comment: Yes, I tried that too, but this is not the same code, look at the code of the objects on the page, it is different

Comment: The reason is in the html, Cloudflare protection. It checks the browser to ensure the request is valid to prevent DDoS attacks. There is a library used for this called "cloudscraper".

Comment: I've updated my answer to show the cloudscraper working with that website

Comment: Have you tried this code? `cloudscraper.exceptions.CloudflareChallengeError: Detected a Cloudflare version 2 challenge, This feature is not available in the opensource (free) version.`

Comment: Yes, i used. It's work! Code from Samt94 also works. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

@Samt94 already has stated that the website is under cloudflare protection. So you can use `cloudscraper` instead of `requests`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import cloudscraper
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper(delay=10,   browser={'custom': 'ScraperBot/1.0',})
url = 'https://standards.globalspec.com/'
req = scraper.get(url)
print(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,'lxml')
```

**Output:**

```
  <Response [200]>
```

[cloudscraper](https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/)